# On a mac, setup CMD - Shift - z to be 'undo-tree-redo'

Tags: key-bindings

This is not working for some reason:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-S-z") 'undo-tree-redo)
```

> CMD - Shift - z

While this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-y") 'undo-tree-redo)
```

works.

How do I get "CMD - Shift - z" to be 'undo-tree-redo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(global-set-key (kbd "s-Z") 'undo-tree-redo)`. (`Z` = `SHIFT + z`). This works for me on Linux with `s-` being the windows key, but should work with the command key on a Mac I think. This threw me off at first as well.